# For /f command in batch multiple lines

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to search through a text file but I am having a problem:

Test.txt:

```
Pizza|Cheese
Filet Mignon|Meat
Bread|Dough
```

How do you use the "for /f" command to look through all the lines and then just echo one thing.
This is where I am right now:

```
for /f "tokens=2*delims=|" %a in (test.txt) do echo %a
```

This echos Cheese, Meat, and Dough. How do I isolate the lines so that for /f looks in those lines and not others.

This is what I want to do:

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="What do you want to eat? "
for /f "tokens=2*delims=|" %a in (test.txt) do (
if Quest=Pizza echo ???         <===This is the area where I am having problems
if Quest="Filet mignon" echo ??? <=What are the commands so I can echo only Cheesy, Meaty, or Dough?
if Quest=Bread echo ???        <===Because what is happening right now is that everything is displayed.
)
Pause
```

Comment: it shows the the three words for me `Cheese,Meat and Dough`

Comment: are you sure the text file new line is not in unix style?

Comment: @npocmaka Yeah, I just tryed again and it showed all three, my problem is trying to isolate the lines so only one things shows up... Not sure what unix style is so I guess no it is not is unix style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting the `%` required for variable. I think this is what you want it to do:

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="What do you want to eat? "
for /f "tokens=1* delims=^|" %%a in (test.txt) do if "%Quest%"=="%%~a" Echo %%b
pause
```

Which asks the user to select a food item and then echo's the ingredient of that food item.

Comment: My CMD version is 6.1.7601 and when I do %%a it says it is unexpected

Comment: The code I have provided is meant for a batch file. Open Notepad --> Copy and Paste this into it --> save as .bat --> Run it

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was putting it directly into cmd so I guess that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: @User_143 Does it work when u put it in a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

As I think you intended:

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="What do you want to eat? "
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  if /i "%Quest%"=="%%a" echo %%b
)
Pause
```

If test.txt were large, it would be more efficient to use FINDSTR to find the line you need:

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="What do you want to eat? "
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr /ibc:"%Quest%|" test.txt') do echo %%a
Pause
```

Comment: your findstr command, where do I tell the batch file to look in test.txt?

Comment: @User_143 - Oops, I forgot to include that argument - all fixed.

Comment: What if I removed the parentheses after "do" in the first code program you gave me? Would it affect it or is it just good practice to have the parentheses? Sorry I am using a Mac at the moment so I can't test it out.

Comment: @User_143 - Sure, you can remove them if you put the IF command after the DO. I added the parentheses and extra lines for formatting to make it easier to read.